# how to runs macro based on value in cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the macro called "macro3" to runs in sheet1

and I have cells B7 in sheet2 that contain the value, lets say "12"

how to runs the macro 12x (based on value in cells B7 in sheet2) with one button?

Comment: Like this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-form-or-a-control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283  ...and to loop: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/4/9/repeat-tasks-with-vba-code-by-looping

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the code below, it is a for-loop:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    
    Dim timesToRun  As Long
    Dim cnt         As Long
    timesToRun = Worksheets(2).Range("B7")
    
    For cnt = 1 To timesToRun
        macro3
    Next cnt
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Viyata - we posted an answer at the exact same time. Should I remove my answer since it's basically a slightly noobish version of yours or should i just let it be? :)

Comment: @DirtyDeffy - Hi! Idk. Do as you wish, it is a free world :)

Comment: @DirtyDeffy Keep it, there is no need to remove it. It's not only about the code, it's also about how you explain your code.

Comment: With that said, none of the answers really explain what is done in the code in my opinion.

Comment: @Andreas - my explanation is quite ok - "take a look at the code below, it is a for-loop:"

Comment: there is room for improvements in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest doing the following:

```
Sub RunMacro()
Worksheets("sheet2").Select

Dim MacroCounter As Integer
MacroCounter = Range("B7").Value

For x = 1 To MacroCounter

    Call macro3

Next x
End Sub
```